# Dynamic variable input value not detected

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase

I am making a form that will allow the user to add a new language. There is another hidden input which will contain the language code (ISO 639-1).

The idea is to automatically update the hidden input with the code (based on what language the user selected).

The language will be added when the user submits the form. However, in Firebase "code" is an empty string.

**.html**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onCreatePost(formData.value)" #formData="ngForm" autocomplete="off" class="form">
    <select id="language-list" name="name" ngModel>
        <option *ngFor="let language of languageList" (click)="getLanguageCode(language.code)">{{ language.name }}</option>                   
            </select>
        <input type="text" name="code" [value]="langCode" ngModel>
        <button type="submit" class="button-primary" [disabled]="!formData.valid"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle margin"></i>Submit</button>
</form>
```

**.ts**

```
langCode = '';

getLanguageCode(code: string) {
    this.langCode = code;
}

onCreatePost(postData: Languages) {
    this.LanguagesService.onCreatePost(postData.id, postData.name, postData.code);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the final intent is to submit the language id, name and code, I guess you could bind your select on the language object as well (instead to play with hidden form value) :

.ts

```
  selectedLanguage: any;
  languageList: any[] = [{ id: 1, code: 'en', name: 'English' },{ id: 2, code: 'fr', name: 'French' }];

  onSubmit() {
      console.log('selectedLanguage', this.selectedLanguage);
  }
```

.html

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #formData="ngForm" autocomplete="off" class="form">
    <select id="language-list" name="langCode" [(ngModel)]="selectedLanguage">
      <option *ngFor="let language of languageList" [ngValue]="language">{{language.name}}</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="button-primary" [disabled]="!(selectedLanguage)"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle margin"></i>Submit</button>
    <p *ngIf="selectedLanguage">Selected language: {{selectedLanguage | json}}</p>
</form>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uk8qyh